# Restrict Certain Pages In WordPress by Country

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I have several products (**WooCommerce**) that are available to all countries.

Due to two products being under contract with a distributor, we have to restrict two products to only be sold outside the USA.

The two products should not show at all if they are trying to be accessed via the USA.

I've tried a couple of plugins and have one semi-working.

It disables the add to cart button, but I would rather it just remove the product from the site altogether, but only if the site is being accessed from the USA.

Everywhere else would be able to see the products.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `WC_Geolocation` class to detect user location and then exclude certain product from being displayed by modifying the products query .

so you can use the following code to achive the desired results.

Based of LoicTheAztec Suggestion i have included another check if the user is logged in and his country is also US then we should also exclude the product regardless of his location.

```
function exclude_product_by_geoloacted_user_country($q)
{

    $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    $country = $location['country'];
    $exluded_product = [28, 27]; //you can add here the products that you want to exclude by id

    if (is_user_logged_in() && WC()->customer->get_billing_country() == "US") {

        $q->set('post__not_in', (array) $exluded_product);
        return $q;
    }

    if ($country == "US") { //here you can specify the country code

        $q->set('post__not_in', (array) $exluded_product);
    }

    return $q;
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'exclude_product_by_geoloacted_user_country');
```

place the code above in your `functions.php` and change the product ids and you are good to go.

code is tested with StoreFront Theme.

Comment: That is the right way, but the only problem is when customer travel… So you should include for logged in users the `WC()->customer->get_billing_country();` instead and for non logged users the GEO LOCATED country.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  correct appreciated your valuable note at this am not of front of my computer I will update my answer is the morning or if it’s  convenient to you if you add second answer:) thanks again